# python 3 : deserialize nested dictionaries from sqlite

Tags: json, python-3.x, sqlite, nested

I have this sqlite3.register_converter function :

```
def str_to_dict(s: ByteString) -> Dict:
    if s and isinstance(s, ByteString):
        s = s.decode('UTF-8').replace("'", '"')
        return json.loads(s)
    raise TypeError(f'value : "{s}" should be a byte string')
```

which returns this exception text :

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 30 (char 29)
```

when encounter with this string :

```
s = b"{'foo': {'bar': [('for', 'grid')]}}"
```

It seems that the issue comes from the nested list/tuple/dictionary but what I don't understand is that in the sqlite shell, the value is correctly returned with a select command :

```
select * from table;
```

whereas the same command issued from a python script returned the exception above :

```
class SqliteDb:

    def __init__(self, file_path: str = '/tmp/database.db'):

        self.file_path = file_path
        self._db = sqlite3.connect(self.file_path, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES | sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
        if self._db:
            self._cursor = self._db.cursor()
        else:
            raise ValueError

        # register data types converters and adapters
        sqlite3.register_adapter(Dict, dict_to_str)
        sqlite3.register_converter('Dict', str_to_dict)

        sqlite3.register_adapter(List, list_to_str)
        sqlite3.register_converter('List', str_to_list)

    def __del__(self):
        self._cursor.close()
        self._db.close()

    def select_from(self, table_name: str):
        with self._db:
            query = f'SELECT * FROM {table_name}'
            self._cursor.execute(query)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        sq = SqliteDb()
        selection_item = sq.select_from("table")[0]
        print(f'selection_item : {selection_item}')

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\n')
        sys.exit(0)
```

s, the value is already saved in database with no issue. Only the selection causes this issue.
So, anybody has a clue why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is really a Python dict literal, and contains structures such as the tuple `('for', 'grid')` that cannot be directly parsed as JSON even after you replace single quotes with double quotes.

You can use `ast.literal_eval` instead to parse the input:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def str_to_dict(s: ByteString) -> Dict:
    return literal_eval(s.decode())
```

Comment: actually as much as I like your answer, I still don't know why the serialization works in the shell and not through the script.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the use of lists instead of tuples solves the issue. But I still don't know why the sqlite shell functions but I learned about ast : so, thanks !